# PassportJS get sessionID before successRedirect

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

So i have this endpoint :

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback',passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/profile',failureRedirect: '/'}));
```

before redirecting the user to other pages I need to save his sessionID to the db for later use.

I have tried this :

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback',
 .authenticate('google', {failureRedirect: '/'}),function(req, res){
   console.log(req.sessionID);//...Save sessionID.....
   res.redirect('/profile');
});
```

But I´m not sure if there are any disadvantages when not including "successRedirect"?

Comment: There is already a `req.session` added by express-session, it should have the sessionID on it https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#reqsession

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the reason why im saving the sessionid is so that I can later on update the session for a specific user.